# Python: How do I remove text between two delimiters WITHOUT IMPORTING MODULE

Tags: python, tags, delimiter, strip

I have searched around for many threads, but they all require importing (BeautifulSoup, regex). The input is a single LARGE string with multiple occurrences of the delimiters ('<', '>') I have heard that pairing tags is a good technique but I am not sure how to go about it.

Example (very small) input:
Actual input is a whole HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
example
<head>
hello
<meta charset="utf-8">
example2
<meta/>
```

Desired Output:

```
example hello example2
```

Comment: Is this one single string, or a list of strings (like imported from a file)?

Comment: It's a single string, but I am open to any solutions.

Comment: So you want to output any text that is not in between `< ... >`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple, understandable approach using a simple loop:

```py
str = '<!DOCTYPE html><html>example<head>hello<meta charset="utf-8">'
words = []
temp = ""
flag = 0
for i in str:
    if i=="<":
        flag = 0
        if temp:
            words.append(temp)
            temp = ""
    elif i==">":
        flag=1
    else:
        if flag==1:
            temp += i
print(words)   # prints ['example', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `tag_depth` variable to zero.

Iterate over the string one character at a time.  If you see a `<` character, increment `tag_depth`, and if you see a `>` character, decrement it.  If you see any other character and `tag_depth` is zero, output the character.

```
tag_depth = 0
for c in mystring:
    if c == '<':
        tag_depth += 1
    elif c == '>':
        tag_depth -= 1
    elif tag_depth == 0:
        print(f"{c}", end=0)
```